# Windows' File Explorer "Map Network Drive" generates an HTTP OPTIONS request that is unauthorized

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, http, authentication, webdav

We are developing a WebDAV server in Java that we would like to serve a Windows' File Explorer client. I can run the following `curl` command that gives a good response:

```
>curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/storage-explorer/rest/dav -u joe:JoeSchmo1!
```

If I try to "Map Network Drive" using the File Explorer while specifying the same user and password as in the `curl` command, I get an "unauthorized" response.

[image]

We are developing a WebDAV server in Java that we would like to serve a Windows' File Explorer client. I can run the following curl command that gives a good response:

> curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/storage-explorer/rest/dav -u joe:JoeSchmo1!
> If I try to "Map Network Drive" using the File Explorer while specifying the same user and password as in the curl command, I get an "unauthorized" response.

I examined the requests and responses using WireShark. For `curl`, I see:

```
OPTIONS /storage-explorer/rest/dav HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic am9lOkpvZVNjaG1vMSE=
User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Server: milton.io-3.0.0.1
Pragma: no-cache
DAV: 1, 2
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2024 17:46:05 GMT
Allow: HEAD, PROPFIND, REPORT, OPTIONS, HEAD, PROPPATCH
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
MS-Author-Via: DAV
```

For File Explorer, I see:

```
OPTIONS /storage-explorer/rest/dav HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.19045
translate: f
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Expires: 0
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 71
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2024 18:06:34 GMT

<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>
```

Another oddity is that I can see activity in our webapp's log for the `curl` request, but not for the File Explorer request.

What is the important difference between the two OPTIONS requests that causes the different responses? What can I do from the File Explorer to have it generate an acceptable request, e.g., one equivalent to `curl`'s?

Based on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector#003), I used `regedit` to modify the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\BasicAuthLevel` setting to allow http, but it made no difference.

I'm open to any debugging suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important difference is this part :

```
Authorization: Basic am9lOkpvZVNjaG1vMSE=
```

The string after the word "Basic" is a base64 encoding of your
user-name and password.
Your WebDAV server evidently doesn't allow anonymous
access to this resource.

I can't know how your page and the server code are programmed,
but evidently the entered user-name/password are not passed on to
the server as inside the generated request.

An alternative to passing the user/password via an `Authorization`
header, is doing that via query parameters appended to the URL,
such as `http://example.com?u=username,p=password`.
Another option is: `http://username:password@example.com/`.

Your WebDAV server should be programmed to understand such parameters.

Comment: You're right our server does not allow anonymous access. Using WireShark, I can't see where File Explorer is attempting to send the user name information.  It doesn't appear to be via query parameters (or anywhere else I can find).  On the server side, there appears to be some (JBoss-supplied?) filter that rejects the request before it gets processed by our code.

Comment: In websites after the connection request is passed successfully, the user is connected and its request is processed automatically. Explorer apparently is different. Have you set the registry item `BasicAuthLevel` to `2` (restart required)? (Note that you're sending the credentials in clear text.)

Comment: I had changed the registry entry, but didn't restart.  Restarting made all the difference.  The request is working now.  (For my local testing, I don't mind the credentials in clear text.  We'll be doing something better in higher environments.)